# Converting date time to epoch time losing an hour in Java/scala

Tags: java, scala, jodatime

I'm trying to convert the date time string `10/10/2015 10:00:00` to the seconds since the unix epoch, which is `1444471200`. However, weirdly I'm getting back the value `1444467600` which is actually `10/10/2015 09:00:00`. Here's my code:

```
// using "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9",
//       "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.8.1",

import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat

val dt = DateTime.parse(dateTimeString, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
dt.getMillis / 1000
```

Where's this hour offset coming from and how can I get rid of it? My local timezone is GMT (which == UTC at the moment anyway)...

Comment: I suspect your local time zone is actually Europe/London, not GMT. They're very different. On October 10th, Europe/London was on UTC+1...

Comment: @JonSkeet Excellent point. You're right. Now Europe/London is at UTC. I was using python to double check my values, so I guess that was giving non-TZ aware dates back. Thanks.

Comment: Lesson to learn here is to always include an offset-from-UTC when serializing a date-time value. Even better, stick to using the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats.

Comment: @BasilBourque Correct. Unfortunately this is third party data :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, it's not parsing with GMT/UTC. Just add that to your `DateTimeFormat`.

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").withZoneUTC()
```

Answer (score 5):

## java.time

The [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33550426/642706) by Sotirios Delimanolis is correct. Here is the same kind of code for the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later, intended as the successor to [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

First we define a formatter. Notice the call-chain, calling [`withZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone-java.time.ZoneId-) to specify the zone by which we want the string parsed. This is not optional, as the input string lacks offset or time zone data.

Then we call the static [`parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) method on [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to actually do the parsing.

Lastly we call the convenience method [`toEpochSecond`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toEpochSecond--) to convert this date-time to the number of seconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

```
String input = "10/10/2015 10:00:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" ).withZone ( ZoneOffset.UTC );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input , formatter );
long secondsFromEpoch = zdt.toEpochSecond ();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | zdt: " + zdt + " | secondsFromEpoch: " + secondsFromEpoch );
```

> input: 10/10/2015 10:00:00 | zdt: 2015-10-10T10:00Z | secondsFromEpoch: 1444471200